# htaccess pretty urls setup

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I'm using htaccess for the first time to make pretty urls for my website html files and 1 php file. I was just wondering if I would be able to get some advice on my htaccess file set up and if how I have it set up is a good way? I'd hate for my urls to not work in some situation because of what I have written. :(

Example html file:

```
before:  http://www.domain.com/subdomain/htmlpage.html
after:   http://www.domain.com/subdomain/htmlpage/
```

Single php file:

```
before:  http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage.php?p=1
after:   http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage/1/
```

I have added in a rule to redirect index.html to index.php. I've also had to add 'base href' in the head of each file because I've used relative links.

the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ phppage.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is `htmlpage` actually now present (stored) as ? `htmlpage.html` (and you just want to make it look like it were a directory) or is the new file now `htmlpage/index.html`?

The difficulty in your current setup - AFAICT - is that you have actually correct URLs that you just want to make look different via both redirecting and rewriting. Things are easier when the old URLs are actually no longer valid, and you can rewrite them to a final, nicer URL.

Comment: htmlpage is present and is stored in the root (subdomain) directory- and the pretty url link loads .htmlpage when you type in /htmlpage/. I'm unsure how to make the .html page not work...But would that be a bad idea if visitors have already bookmarked a .html page?

Comment: It's not about breaking things. But if you essentially rewrite "file.html" to "file" and then have your webserver auto-rewrite that internally back to "file.html" you can easily end up in a redirect loop when you mess something up.
That's why I asked whether your 'file' (on the server) is called `..dirs/somepage.html`, `...dirs/somepage/index.html` or whatever. Independent of the URL(s) you want to serv it under.

Comment: Jess: reading your other comments I'm unsure if you need to receive from the user the URI `phppage.php?p=1` and rewrite it to `phppage/1` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ phppage.php?p=$1 [L]
```

is going to send some pages to phppage.php even though they don't look like

```
http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage/1/
```

because there is no mention of phppage in the first argument to RewriteRule.

Comment: Ohhh yeah I can see it not changing the 1, so pages /2/,/3/,/4/ etc all stay as phppage/1/ :( If you don't mind, what would I need to write to change this? :S

Comment: RewriteRule ^subdomain/phppage/([^/\.]+)/?$ phppage.php?p=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect http://www.domain.com/subdomain/htmlpage.html to http://www.domain.com/subdomain/htmlpage/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/subdomain/[^/]+)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/ [L,R=301]


#redirect http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage.php?p=1 to http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage/1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/subdomain/[^/]+)\.php$ [NC]
# or alternatively if page is literally phppage uncomment below and comment above
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/subdomain/phppage)\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/ [L,R=301]

#if url does not end with /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/subdomain/.+[^/])$ [NC]
# and its not for an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# put one trailing slash
RewriteRule . %1/ [L,R=301]

#write http://www.domain.com/subdomain/htmlpage/ to htmlpage.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomain/([^/]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1.html [L]   


#write http://www.domain.com/subdomain/phppage/1/ to phppage.php?p=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomain/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . phppage.php?p=%1 [L]
```