# Friendly php URL for multiple languages using htaccess file (detect language from URL)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multi language php script which use URLs to detecting which language files should be load from template folder for user.

for example:

English version: `site.com/etc.php` or `site.com/etc.php?lang=EN`

Arabic version: `site.com/etc.php?lang=AR`

but I want to have more pretty and also SEO friendlier URLs. So I need to detect language by a nicer way from URLs.

for example:

English version: `site.com/EN/etc.php`

Arabic version: `site.com/AR/etc.php`

is this possible by .htaccess file? (I search for solutions in stackoverflow, but it didn't work...)

Thank you
Amir

Comment: This is what you're looking ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332544/htaccess-pretty-urls-setup

Comment: @Sobiaholic Thank you for reply, but it's not works for me.
I don't know apache well, so I need exact help for my URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have these rules in your document root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+\.php)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+?)/?$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use it in my local host and when I go to "http://127.0.0.0/site/AR/" I get error: (The requested URL /site/AR/ was not found on this server.).

Comment: I use your code on my online site and it's work! perfect! Thank you. :) But I have one problem. when I go to `site.com/AR/` or `site.com/EN/` I get 404 error. how can I fix it to show index.php files by these URLs?

Comment: It's work! Thank you @anubhava :) is this code cause any overloading server resources or slow down on page's loading times?

Comment: No these are simple rules, this will not cause any additional load to server.

Comment: Thank so much, that's very helpful. But I also like to learn these kind of appache codes too, could you please give me some references for beginers like me? :D Thank you

Comment: @anubhava Perfect! You saved my day!