# .htaccess questions regarding urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

1. I would like to get rid of the .php at the end of each page name on my domain.
2. When users hit the "home" button I would like the "mommy-info/index.php" to not show up (since it is the same as "mommy-info.com")
3. Is it possible to display a different page name in the url other than what the file is named or would I need to rename the files? (i.e. mommy-info.com/healthsplash.php would display as mommy-info.com/Health-and-Nutrition)
4. I would like certain pages (those that have the word "splash" in it) to act as directories in the url, so (/preexercise would show up as /health/prenatal-exercise)

I have created the .htaccess file in the web root folder on cPanel using GoDaddy's web hosting. I've reviewed several of the other posts similar to mine, and it didn't work.

My .htaccess . The first section is supposed to remove the .php, but it doesn't. The second, I believe is for the trailing slash.

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess pretty urls setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332544/htaccess-pretty-urls-setup)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect URL to custom URL through .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382686/redirect-url-to-custom-url-through-htaccess)